# Div Padding differences between Mozilla and everyone else

Tags: css, firefox, padding

I have a div element with a background image that I am vertically trying to align some text in.

The text pads itself one way in IE, Chrome and Safari but one pixel differently in Firefox 3 / 4.

It's one pixel lower in Firefox and is driving me nuts.  Normally it wouldn't be that big of a deal but I am vertically centering text in a caption bubble so I need it to be perfect.

Anyone know why it's different in Firefox and whether there is a workaround?  Something like a -moz-padding-top would be super even though I know that doesn't exist.

The padding that's giving me issues is set below in .moodInner

```
#content .profilePic
{
    float:right;
    width:230px;
    padding:10px 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
}
#content .profilePic #moodOuter
{
    height:36px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    width:100%;
    background:url('/_assets/img/mood-bubble-profile.gif') no-repeat center;
}   
#content .profilePic #moodInner
{
    padding:4px 0 0 0;
    font-size:0.85em;
}
<div class="profilePic">
     <div id="moodOuter" style="display:
            <?php if ($mood == "") { ?>none;<?php } else { ?>block;<?php } ?>">
            <div id="moodInner"><?php echo trim($mood); ?></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of css reset to wipe any default browser styles?

Comment: I don't even know what that means so most likely no, I'm not doing that =)

Comment: Each browser has some default styles associated with it (mostly margin & padding) to make non-styled content readable. But each browsers default is different, so resetting the styles ensures that there isn't padding between your background and the browser window. The defaults can also apply some minimal styling to other block elements. But seeing as how you have defined the padding this may not be the problem. [Css Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) Add that at the beginning of your Css, but use with caution it might mess up some things if you have already set styles.

Comment: I just looked up a CSS reset and yeah, I'm doing that (* { margin:0;padding:0;}.  Any other ideas?

Comment: The problem may be the ems on the font-size. Firefox, unlike other browsers, will render partial pixel font sizes; for example, Firefox will actually try and figure out what 8.4px font-size looks like, instead of rounding to 8px like other browsers. I would first try setting your font-size to a hard pixel value, just to make sure that isn't the problem.

Comment: That is interesting.  I was always under the impression that declaring font sizes in em was better practice than px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `font-size` of `#moodInner` to a `px` value instead of an `em` one.. calculating ems to pixels could be causing the default line-height to differ by a px across browsers

You can't have half a pixel, so when making an em conversion and the outcome equates to a partial pixel, the browsers have to "round" and they all round differently

Comment: It was a combination of yours and jlego's answer.  Changing the font size from em to px did the trick along with eliminating moodInner and adding line-height.  I flipped a coin to see who gets the check mark and you won with heads.

Comment: Thanks :).. I upvoted @jlego so s/he gets half ;) - both solutions indeed were line-height related so removing the rounding and/or fixing them both indeed should work!

Answer (score 3):

I would try removing #moodInner altogether, placing the content of if into #moodOuter and setting a line height on it (only works if your text is 1 line). The line-height should be the same as the height. This will vertically center your text inside #moodOuter. (although i am not sure if it will fix your problem.)

```
#moodOuter {
  height: 36px
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: It was a combination of yours and clairesuzy's answer.  Changing the font size from em to px did the trick along with eliminating moodInner and adding line-height.  I flipped a coin to see who gets the check mark and you lost with tails =(